# Is it possible for Mongodb search query to ignore non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: mongodb

For example my data consists of :

```
[
   {username: "velikiye.lucky 09", region: "Hamburg"},
   {username: "Roger. blue", region: "Hamburg"},
]
```

If I put query to search for "**roger blue**" (note that I don't use the dot character in my query)

How to get `{username: "roger. blue", region: "Hamburg"}` in mongoDB ? Currently I had to load all data from the database, remove all non-alphanumeric characters in it, lower-case it, and then search for the requested username.

Comment: I think you'll have to do regex-based search

Comment: how do I ignoring that non alphanumeric characters ? It could be in the middle, it could be everywhere. Not only dots, it could be a dash, or asterisks, etc

Comment: Something like this. https://mongoplayground.net/p/mWrJU1d-SPc

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Thank you for a concrete example. I expand your answer so that it will ignore all non-alphanumeric characters (your example only catering for dot)  `[^a-zA-Z0-9]*roger[^a-zA-Z0-9]*blue[^a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use regex-match like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  username: {
    $regex: "(.*)roger(.*)blue(.*)",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ic0E8i3H4oy)

Here, (.*) will ignore any character. If you only want to ignore non-alphanumeric characters, then as you mentioned in the comments, try this:

```
db.collection.find({
  username: {
    $regex: "[^a-zA-Z0-9]*roger[^a-zA-Z0-9]*blue[^a-zA-Z0-9]*",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cmu3iNMzcnP)